# Unable to get logs from Kubernetes POD

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-pod

I am new to Kubernetes and currently working on logging.
What I have tried so far is using minikube, created a mount-point and by using PV/PVC I am mounting it in POD.

The problem I am having is when I do `kubectl logs test-app` I did not get any logs.
But when I do:

```
kubectl exec -it test-app -- bash

[root@test-app /]# tail -f /var/log/test.log 
Mon Jul 4 06:36:31 UTC 2022
Mon Jul 4 06:36:36 UTC 2022
Mon Jul 4 06:36:41 UTC 2022
Mon Jul 4 06:36:46 UTC 2022
Mon Jul 4 06:36:51 UTC 2022
Mon Jul 4 06:36:56 UTC 2022
```

I get the logs. My question is how can I get these logs with 'kubectl logs test-app' ?

**pv-pvc.yaml**

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: task-pv-volume
  labels:
    type: local
spec:
  storageClassName: manual
  capacity:
    storage: 10Gi
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  hostPath:
    path: "/mnt/data"
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: task-pv-claim
spec:
  storageClassName: manual
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 3Gi
```

**test-pod.yaml**

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: test-app
spec:
  volumes:
  - name: ps
    persistentVolumeClaim:
      claimName: task-pv-claim
  containers:
  - name: app
    image: centos
    command: ["/bin/sh"]
    args: ["-c", "while true; do echo $(date -u) >> /var/log/test.log; sleep 5; done"]
    volumeMounts:
    - mountPath: "/var/log"
      name: ps
```

Comment: try removing this part: `>> /var/log/test.log`. k8s collects logs from stdout/stderr of your process and not from /var/log

Comment: Alternatively you can replace it with `| tee /var/log/test.log` if you really want to have your log go into both your pvc and kube's log system.

Comment: You could send applicative logs to stderr to try to monitor your bash command. `>&2 ` at the end of your command. Or for example, in python, you can use `logger` and send to `stderr` you app logs and also to file. In every language you should find an alternative to send to setderr and to a file

Comment: @Aron I tried that, but it didn't work. It would be good if I can log to both pvc and kube's log

Comment: @niceguy try `| tee -a /var/log/test.log` Since you keep calling echo, you want `tee` to append to the log file. https://askubuntu.com/a/808543/767423

Answer (score 3):

Kubernetes only collects container logs written to stdout and this is what you get from `kubectl logs`. For more information, please refer to the [documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/cluster-administration/logging/#basic-logging-in-kubernetes).

If you need to collect logs that are written to a file, you will have to use a more sophisticated log collector like [fluentd](https://www.fluentd.org/) or [fluentbit](https://fluentbit.io/).